# Local testing for cloud composer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer

What's the best way to replicate cloud composer in a local environment?
Before we deploy our code, we want to test it locally, for this, we already use a docker-compose set up with the image apache/airflow:1.10.14, since we use airflow 1.10.14+composer in GCP, However, they don't have the same behavior.

Any tips are appreciated!

Comment: For me, I create a Linux Compute Engine with 4 cores and 16GB of RAM running Debian.  I then install Docker and run Airflow as a Docker container.  This gives me a full sandbox to play with that is not Composer.  I would use Composer for production but I get my own sandbox to "play with".

Answer (score 1):

You can create a repository in a local environment so you can test how it is going to work with your project. In [this](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/composer-airflow-codebase#about_the_repository) link you can see how you can achieve and create the repository without a problem in your local environment.

If you can see in the document there's a warning that the repository is not based for production testing but since this is for local testing you don't need to worry about it.